# What is the probability that both the numbers are odd with given conditions?

Tags: probability

> 2 Numbers are selected at random from the integers 1 through 9.If the sum is even,find the probability that both the numbers are odd.

My approach:

A:Event of getting sum as even, B:Event of getting both the numbers as odd

p(B/A)=
I think to calculate the sum  as even we do like this

(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(1,9)

Similarly (2,2),(2,4),(2,6),(2,8) etc for

3,1....4,2......5,1..6,2....,7,1..8,2.......9,1...

There are 28 such Numbers.

I think i am doing wrong because the Ans are not considering any such calculations and i am not aware of why i am doing wrong.

Expected Ans:5/8

Comment: This needs some clarification.  Are you requiring that the two numbers be different? Also, I can see why you are looking at pairs of the form $(1,3)$ etc. as their sum is even, but why would you count the pairs of the form $(2,1)$ etc.?  The sum is odd for them.

Comment: @lulu ya typo mistake.Thanku so much.

Comment: @lulu Nothing is mentioned in the question about the difference in numbers

Comment: As the posted answer shows, the answer is different depending on whether you allow duplicates.

Comment: How do you get $28$ pairs? - that is unclear to me - you should have $32$ or $41$, and $32$ is consistent with the answer (this is the case with no doubles e.g. $(2,2)$ would not be allowed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are five odd numbers and four even ones. Given that we drew either two odds or two evens, what is the probability that we drew two odds?

Assuming we drew with replacement:

Probability of two evens is $(4/9)^2$. Probability of two odds is $(5/9)^2$. Therefore the relative probability of two odds is $\frac{(5/9)^2}{(4/9)^2+(5/9)^2} = \frac{25}{16+25} = \frac{25}{41}$.

Assuming we drew without replacement:

Probability of two evens is $(4/9)(3/8)$. Probability of two odds is $(5/9)(4/8)$. Therefore the relative probability of two odds is $\frac{(5/9)(4/8)}{(4/9)(3/8) + (5/9)(4/8)} = \frac{20}{12+20} = \frac{10}{16} = \frac{5}{8}$.

The key is to notice that we don't care which numbers were picked, but only their odd/even nature.

Answer (score 2):

For the same sample space, simpler to compute favorable/total number of ways

*Without replacement:*

Ways of drawing two odd numbers = ${5\choose 2} = 10$

Ways of drawing two even numbers = ${4\choose 2} = 6$

P(draw 2 odd numbers | sum is even) = $\dfrac{10}{6+10} = \dfrac{5}{8}$

*With replacement*

Ways of drawing two odd numbers = $5\cdot5 = 25$

Ways of drawing two even numbers = $4\cdot4 = 16$

P(draw 2 odd numbers | sum is even) = $\dfrac{25}{25+16} = \dfrac{25}{41}$

Answer (score -1):

Its answer would be like 
there will 16 cases such as 
(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(1,9),(3,5),(3,7),(3,9),(5,7),(5,9),(7,9),(2,4),(2,6),(2,8),(4,6),(4,8),(6,8).
as given in question we want odd no. so there will be only 10 case(1st 10 cases).

10c1/16c1=10/16=5/8